# renderDataTable not creating data frames from dynamic data

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app where user selects the required fields from the drop down menu to display the data table. I am using renderDataTable to display the raw data. The output data table changes with my drop down selection. From that raw data, I want to create graphs to summarize the data, which would require a data frame.

Firstly, I am making my drop down selections reactive. This is the code for it:

```
Table1 <- reactive({
input$names1
input$names2
})
```

An then I am using these selections in my renderDataTable statement:

```
output$Data <- renderDataTable({
Table2 <- as.data.frame(sqlQuery(dbhandle, paste0("select a, b, c from Table where column = ",input$names1," and column2 = ",input$names2,""))) })
```

How do I create a data frame out of the raw data using renderDataTable?

Comment: we are here to help you solve your issues. Rather then completely answering. Please let us us know what efforts have you put to do this.

Comment: Hi @Nehal, just edited my code to show the process. I am new to R, so couldn't try much. Do you have any idea where the root cause is ? I want to use this 'Table2' to create graphs.

Comment: @AkshayFadnavis Your code chunks don't help much, because they are wrong in an obvious way. I don't mean to be rude, I just want so say, that it would help to know exactly what `Table1`, etc. **should be**. Because the way it is now, `Table1()` will have the value `input$names2` (since its the last evaluated expression), which is **obviously** not what you want it to be. Same with `Table2`: Do you want it to be another `data.frame` or is it just a name inside `renderDataTable`? Knowing what you want (with possible sample data), we can show you how it's done.

Comment: Table1 is just a name of the function in which I have 2 reactive input elements, while Table2 is the name of the table which I want to make a dynamic data frame. Anyways, I got the solution. Thanks for comment.